# How to resolve paths containing double dot directory references in powershell

Tags: powershell

Is there an easy way in Powershell to resolve a path like

```
c:\a\b\c\..\d
```

so that the result is

```
c:\a\b\d
```

Comment: @phuclv I wouldn't consider this a valid duplicate since this isn't about combining multiple paths but rather getting the absolute path of one relative path.

Comment: @Filburt it's not about combining paths but about the use of `[IO.Path]::GetFullPath`

Answer (score 1):

You could use a System.Uri to get the absolute path:

```
$p = New-Object System.Uri("c:\a\b\c\..\d")
$p.AbsolutePath
```